# HP Elitebook 8440p not booting from flash drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb-flash-drive, hp-elitebook

I'm currently running a dual-boot system with Ubuntu and Kali Linux, and I'd like to install windows 10. I have a USB flash drive with 8 gigabytes of storage space, that is acting as a windows 10 installer (created with Microsoft Media Creation tool on a friend's Windows 7 Professional laptop).

Whenever I restart the laptop, I go straight to F9 (Boot device options), but my USB drive is not appearing. I tested the device on the friend's laptop, and it works just fine.

I've formatted the USB and gone through the Media Creation process many times, but all yielding the same results: there is no usb device detected. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you check if the support of USB ports during boot (USB Legacy) is enabled? See the HP 8440P user manual about this: [link](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/359104/Hp-Elitebook-8440p.html?page=155)

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. I actually just booted the laptop from a Rescatux Live USB drive.